# Multiple SQL queries in a report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

The requirement is to generate a single report connecting to a single DB:

1. Query1 is a group by query and has a bar chart and pie chart based on it.
2. Query2 is a simple query on which a table gets created.

Both these queries need results based on a `WHERE` clause, which is supplied dynamically.

Can somebody point me to some examples on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks very generic requirements. Refer to Jasper documentation or jasper book. you'll find such examples. Look for sub reports and dataset sections to address your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell JasperReports to use a parameter to define part of the query using the `$P!{PARAMETER_NAME}` syntax. This tells JasperReports to use the literal value of `PARAMETER_NAME` as part of the query. You can then do:

1. Create a parameter named `WHERE_CLAUSE` in the report.
2. Give `WHERE_CLAUSE` a default value of `1=1`.
3. Consider the following SQL statement:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE $P!{WHERE_CLAUSE}
   ```

The `$P!` expression changes the literal SQL statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1
```

That is a valid query. Note the difference between `$P{}` and `$P!{}` -- the exclamation mark (`!`) is important.

You can then supply the SQL conditions dynamically.